# E-mail from cron missing newlines from script output, why?

Tags: bash, cron

I have a crontab which executes a shell script and if there is output I expect to see the output in my e-mail:

Here is what the crontab entry looks like:

```
*/2 * * * * /bin/check_perms.sh
```

The actual script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a fix_dirs

fix_dirs=(`cat $(dirname $0)/dirs_to_fix.txt`)

for dir in "${fix_dirs[@]}"; do
   find $dir -type d ! -perm -go=xw -exec stat -c '%U %n %A' {} +
   find $dir -type f ! -perm -go=w -exec stat -c '%U %n %A' {} +
done
```

I am guessing the output of the find is the problem, but if I redirect to a file the file has newlines. When I get the email from cron it is missing all the newlines between files returned by find.

UPDATE: It was just a mail client "issue" I found a way to disable Outlook's behavior here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287816

Comment: are you checking e-mails with Outlook? Is it displaying "extra line breaks removed" in the top of the reading pane?

Comment: Yes I am using Outlook and see the message.

Comment: Then that's your problem. The message is fine, but the viewer is terminally broken. You might want to change the cron job to generate HTML out of the raw output or something if you don't want to switch to a sane email client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your email client is removing the newlines. Try looking at the message source in your email client.